# Is it normal to have two running wpa_supplicants?

Tags: raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to debug issues with wifi connectivity of my RPi 3 (it just randomly loses connection sometimes). And I noticed that

`ps aux | grep wpa_supplicant` gives me:

```
root       310  0.0  0.4  10708  3636 ?        Ss   lut16   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       397  0.0  0.4  11080  3140 ?        Ss   lut16   0:01 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

I'm using a minimal Raspbian Buster and the only thing that I've done is that I configured the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=PL

network={
        ssid="[MyExtender]"
        bssid=[MyExtendersMac]
        psk=""
}
```

Is it normal?

If yes - then why there are two instances of wpa_supplicant?

If no - how to get rid of one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there are two instances of wpa_supplicant?

The first command is called by the `wpa_supplicant.service`,see :

```
systemctl cat wpa_supplicant.service
```

The second one is executed manually:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

Multiple wpa_supplicant instances to configure the same network interface may conflict, to stop them, run:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
```

or:

```
killall wpasupplicant
```

Then cleanly start a new instance manually.

Comment: I dug into it deeper, and it looks like the first one comes from the `wpa_supplicant` service, and the second one is being run by the `dhcpcd` service (the code for this seems to be in the `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` . I disabled the `wpa_supplicant` service, let's see if it'll help with my connection issues. Thanks!

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda, did disabling `wpa_supplicant.service` solve your connection issues?

Comment: @canochordo Disabling the `wpa_supplicant` doesn't solve the issue. You need to kill the running instance.

Comment: For those who want to try this `sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service`